# Workbooks.add fault 1004

Tags: excel, vba

I got this code:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Add("J:\Planning\Sjablonen\Projectsjabloon.xlsm")
```

I run the code with a form control element and get this error:
Error 1004 Method Add of Object Sheets failed

The path I use is on a local server and the file really exists. This was working a week ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Workbooks.Add` method will take an optional Template argument but it has to be XlWBATemplate constant or a file name with path.  The [Office Dev Centre Workbooks.Add method help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.add?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm203073)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue) explains it in greater detail.  It doesn't explicitly specify the file must be a `.xltx` or `xltm` file type, it is implied in

> If this argument is a string specifying the name of an existing Microsoft Excel file, the new workbook is created with the specified file as a template.

If you want to use `Projectsjabloon.xlsm` as a template you'll need to save it as a macro-enabled template `.xltm` file. You can then include it in the optional Template argument:

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Add("J:\Planning\Sjablonen\Projectsjabloon.xltm")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

    Dim wk As Workbook

    Set wk = Workbooks.Add
    wk.SaveAs Filename:=("J:\Planning\Sjablonen\Projectsjabloon.xlsm")

End Sub
```